# Weird bug when inserting DateTime to sql server 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

I'm inserting a datetime field to sql server. From my local computer it works just fine. example: the datetime field in sql server is : "2013-07-31 08:00:00.000", but when I run the application form the server it switches the day and month and insert it like this: 
"2013-07-31 15:15:00.000".

My relevant page loads some entries from the sql server depending on today's date.
Like this:

```
public List<act_event> return_event_list(DateTime date) //return all events for spesific date
    {

        List<act_event> event_list = new List<act_event>();

        String date_sql = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");


        using (SqlConnection con = connect("igroup20_test2ConnectionString"))
        {

            using (SqlCommand cmd = create_command(con, "select * from act_events where  '" + date_sql + "'>=(CAST(e_start as DATE)) and '" + date_sql + "'<=(CAST(e_end as DATE))"))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        act_event a_event = new act_event();
                        a_event.e_num = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["e_num"]);
                        a_event.name = rdr["e_name"].ToString();
                        a_event.start = Convert.ToDateTime(rdr["e_start"]);
                        a_event.end = Convert.ToDateTime(rdr["e_end"]);
                        a_event.description = rdr["e_description"].ToString();
                        a_event.address = rdr["e_address"].ToString();

                        event_list.Add(a_event);


                    }
                }
            }
        }


        return event_list;


    }
```

**This is how I insert the datetime fields:**

```
public void add_event(act_event add_avent)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = connect("igroup20_test2ConnectionString"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = create_command(con, "insert into act_events values(@e_name, @e_start, @e_end, @e_description, @e_address)"))
            {


                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e_name", add_avent.name);

                SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter("@e_start", SqlDbType.DateTime);
                param2.Value = add_avent.start;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param2);

                SqlParameter param3 = new SqlParameter("@e_end", SqlDbType.DateTime);
                param3.Value = add_avent.end;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param3);

                //cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@e_start", SqlDbType.DateTime));
                //cmd.Parameters["@e_start"].Value = DateTime.Parse(add_avent.start.ToString());



                //cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@e_end", SqlDbType.DateTime));
                //cmd.Parameters["@e_end"].Value = DateTime.Parse(add_avent.end.ToString());

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e_description", add_avent.description);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e_address", add_avent.address);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            //using (SqlCommand cmd2=create_command
        }


    }
```

**I tried changing the select command, adding this:**

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = create_command(con, "select * from act_events where ( '" + date_sql + "'>=(CAST(e_start as DATE)) and '" + date_sql + "'<=(CAST(e_end as DATE)) ) or ( '" + date_sql2 + "'>=(CAST(e_start as DATE)) and '" + date_sql2 + "'<=(CAST(e_end as DATE)) ) "))
```

but for some of the dates it gives me an error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

What should I do?

**EDIT:**

I tried to run the query from the sql studio itself like this:

```
select * from act_events where ( '2013-08-03'>=(CAST(e_start as DATE)) and '2013-08-03'<=(CAST(e_end as DATE)) ) or ( '2013-03-08'>=(CAST(e_start as DATE)) and '2013-03-08'<=(CAST(e_end as DATE)) )
```

it gives me:

[image]

But if I run it like this: (different date)

```
select * from act_events where ( '2013-07-30'>=(CAST(e_start as DATE)) and '2013-07-30'<=(CAST(e_end as DATE)) ) or ( '2013-30-07'>=(CAST(e_start as DATE)) and '2013-30-07'<=(CAST(e_end as DATE)) )
```

it gives me this error:

[image]

**EDIT2:**

**After James suggestion I made a parameterized query like this:**

```
String date_sql = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String date_sql2 = date.ToString("yyyy-dd-MM");

        using (SqlConnection con = connect("igroup20_test2ConnectionString"))
        {

                using (SqlCommand cmd = create_command(con, "select * from act_events where @date1>=(CAST(e_start as DATE)) and @date2<=(CAST(e_end as DATE))"))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1", date_sql);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date2", date_sql);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date3", date_sql2);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date4", date_sql2);
```

which still won't load the correct entries from the sql server

**Then I tried this query:**

```
String date_sql = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String date_sql2 = date.ToString("yyyy-dd-MM");

        using (SqlConnection con = connect("igroup20_test2ConnectionString"))
        {

            using (SqlCommand cmd = create_command(con, "select * from act_events where ( @date1>=(CAST(e_start as DATE)) and @date2<=(CAST(e_end as DATE)) ) or ( @date3>=(CAST(e_start as DATE)) and @date4<=(CAST(e_end as DATE)) )"))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1", date_sql);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date2", date_sql);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date3", date_sql2);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date4", date_sql2);
```

And again it just give me:

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Comment: `yyyy-MM-dd` is an amiguous format with `datetime` (but not for `date`). It is interpreted according to the default language of the login. `yyyyMMdd` is unamiguous.

Answer (score 5):

It's never ever really a good idea to try pass date/time's to SQL as `string` from the client unless you are absolutely certain of the server locale.

Switching to a parameterized query should resolve your issue.

Comment: It isn't really susceptible to SQL Injection. The `return_event_list` function accepts a `DateTime` not a string. (though parameterised queries would avoid this issue and make better use of the plan cache)

Comment: @MartinSmith ah yeah, good point actually never noticed that.

Comment: You say I should swith to parameterized query but even when I'm selecting it from the sql query it gives my this error . Check my edit

Comment: @Dvirski your edit doesn't change anything. Your `select` query needs to be parameterized, not just your `insert` statement. The problem is you are passing the date in a *specific* format but the server is expecting it in a different one. Switching to a parameterized query should allow SQL to decide which format it needs the date in.

Comment: Check my edit. it still won't do the job. even with parameterized query... btw I appreciate your answers : )

Comment: **Please** stop converting the dates to strings and then casting them to dates again. A parameterized query passes a DATE as a **DATE**, there is no need to convert back and forth. Your mistake is that you pass the dates as strings, even when you use parameters

Comment: @Dvirski as per @PanagiotisKanavos' comment, your still doing the same thing...don't convert the date to `string`, simply pass it straight into the `AddWithValue` method and let SQL deal with formatting it.

Comment: ah I got you. But this still won't solve my problem. the date still gets inserted with the day and month switched, so when I load events those events won't show up

Comment: Not it does not. Not unless you convert it to string. Either your column is a string type, or you are still doing a cast

Answer (score 1):

The problems you encounter are due to string to date conversions in one point or another, both on the client and the server's side

You don't need to do any conversionf to string or date if you use a parameterized query and you pass DateTime values, provided of course that the type of your table's fields is also a date type.

The following code makes no conversions at all:

```
DateTime date1=DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1);
DateTime date2=DateTime.Today.AddMonths(1);

using (SqlConnection con = connect("igroup20_test2ConnectionString"))
{

    using (SqlCommand cmd = create_command(con, 
       "select * from act_events where " +
        "  (@date1>=e_start  and @date1 <= e_end) " + 
        "  or (@date2>= e_start and @date2 <= e_end) "))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1", date1);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date2", date2);
```

You don't need to specify the same date multiple times. If this query doesn't work it's either because the `e_start` and `e_end` fields are text fields or the WHERE clause is not what you expected.

You should also check whether `@date2` is used correctly. Your query seems to look for records that cover `@date1` or don't cover `@date2`. Is this correct?